# Plugging phones into tablets

Tags: tablet, tethering

I have an android tablet (1) and phone (2). Using the phone as a wireless hotspot drains the battery almost as fast as having the phone screen on. I'd like to be able to use it as a tethered hotspot and charge the phone from the larger battery in the tablet (3) but I have two problems - micro usb to micro usb cables don't seem to exist and i'm not sure that a micro to usb converter + a micro usb to usb cable is worth setting up - does it do anything useful?

1. motorola xoom - answer may be honeycomb specific
2. nexus one
3. Copying files would be nice but is a plus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to enable USB host mode on your xoom. Google this for some more details on this - you will need a rooted xoom; there will also be links to USB OTG (on the go) cables that will let you use this (most of them seem to be micro-USB to USB female, into which you would then need to plug your normal USB cable).

I don't know if this USB OTG configuration would actually charge your phone - some USB OTG don't provide power at all.

Copying files would work on this really easily (I think that's what it's generally been done for), but network may be a little trickier - it would rely on the xoom having the usb network drivers for your N1, which it might not (in that case you'd need to compile the drivers/kernel modules for your xoom, where it starts to get messy :-/ )

Comment: Sorry for dropping off the radar. It certainly sounds sensible, but as it happens I've upgraded to a galaxy nexus so I've not tested your answer as my xoom is mostly just sitting in my bag looking forlorn.